# Wordpress doesn't show up my page template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a template called **page-example-template.php**. Then I go to my home page and choose this template but when I use this template, it doesn't show up in my home page.

I put some code to try but actually there is a carousel, not some paragraph.

here is the code:

```html
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Example Template
*/
?>

   <div class="container pb-5">
      <p> Example </p>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need the `*` before template name for it to be interpreted by Wordpress

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Example Template
 */
```